# Is there a way to `new` a .NET object aligned to 64 bytes?

Tags: c#, memory-alignment

There are functions like [`_aligned_malloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for C and C++ but I can't find anything for aligning .NET objects in memory.

Comment: Why would you use C# but want to care about memory-level concerns?  The whole point of high-level languages is to abstract those kinds of things away.

Comment: C# is a managed  language. The CLR manages all memory related aspects so you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: .NET has field alignment attributes. Obviously they give some facilities for controlling memory related aspects.

Comment: @Nick: That's for interop purposes. Is that what you're doing here?

Comment: .NET's field alignment attributes are intended solely for the purpose of interacting with unmanaged code via P/Invoke.

Comment: One way to do it is to allocate too much memory and then only use the next nearest aligned part. e.g. if you get allocated a pointer at 0x..31 then round up to 0x...40 and use that. (You'll need to account for the extra size yourself.)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible in the general case to usefully align a .net object on a 64-bit boundary, because even if an object starts out on a 64-bit boundary there's no guarantee that it won't be relocated to an odd multiple of 32 bits.  For some reason, .net seems to think it's worthwhile to force arrays of more than a thousand `double` values to the Large Object Heap, which is always 64-bit aligned but is otherwise horrible, and yet provides no useful means of requesting 64-bit alignment for other objects even though doing so should not be difficult or costly (round up object sizes in gen0; when moving objects to higher-numbered generations, pair up odd-sized objects).

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTION -- You will need to create a P/Invocable DLL, and then call into it to perform the aligned_malloc function. Sample C++ code

```
#include <malloc.h>

extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) void* alMlc(size_t size, size_t alginment) {
    return _aligned_malloc(size,alginment);
}
}
```

C# code (assuming the DLL you created is called mallocer.dll)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("mallocer.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern IntPtr alMlc(int size, int alignment);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                //Allocate exactly 64 bytes of unmanaged memory, aligned at 64 bytes
                char* str = (char*)alMlc(64,64).ToPointer();
                str[0] = 'H';
                str[1] = 'i';
                str[2] = '!';
                str[3] = '\0';

                Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(new IntPtr(str)));

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Allocates 64 bytes of unmanaged memory, casts it to a char*, sets some text in it, and prints it to the screen. Exactly 64-bytes is allocated for str.

Comment: And the 64 bytes is aligned at 64 bytes

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit CPU int might be long instead

Comment: Apologies for necro-comment:

The reason for aligning to 64-byte boundaries may be in the interests of invoking AVX512 instructions further down the line. If memory serves, and there's every potential the following assertion being entirely incorrect along with my memory of such, the CPU has to realign non-512-bit-aligned SIMD data to 512-bit-aligned prior to invoking any SIMD instructions, thus ruining any potential performance gains.

Same for AVX256 (32-byte-aligned) and so on.